# Python - Is it possible to round and replace an array at the same time?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace

How can I round and replace an array at the same time?
My code line:

```
plt.text(*max_p_tranformed[:-1][0]+1, *max_p_tranformed[:-1][1], (str(np.round(deflp1[idx]),2).replace(' [', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')))
```

And the return is: str() argument 2 must be str, not int

Any suggestion to overcome this?

Comment: It looks like you put the closing `)` for the `round` call at the wrong position: it should go after the `2`. Right now you have `str(round(x), 2)` but it should be `str(round(x, 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

After another test, here is the answer:

```
plt.text(*max_p_tranformed[:-1][0]+1, *max_p_tranformed[:-1][1], str(np.round(deflp1[idx],2)).replace(' [', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```